# How to detox filenames in a bash script with no errors posted?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
detox 1.4.5

To display above:

```shell
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
detox -V
```

Here is a toxic filename, starts with s1:

```
s1 Ä Ö Ü - ä ö ü Science & < > " 1 \ 2 ⁄ 3 | ? * (&&9&&&) ::::z.pdf
```

`script1` was copied and pasted into Terminal.
`script1` output works on above toxic filename `"$FILE1"` :

```shell
filename_before_detox='s1 Ä Ö Ü - ä ö ü Science & < > " 1 \ 2 ⁄ 3 | ? * (&&9&&&) ::::z.pdf'
filename_after__detox= s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
```

`script1` works, giving result, a detoxed filename. No spaces and no special characters:
see desired converted, renamed, filename below:

```shell
s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
```

`script1`:

```
clear 
DIR1=$HOME/Downloads    # DIR1=/home/x/Downloads 
cd $DIR1
ls -alF s1*    # List all filenames starting with s1
FILE1='s1 Ä Ö Ü - ä ö ü Science & < > " 1 \ 2 ⁄ 3 | ? * (&&9&&&) ::::z.pdf'
  detox -s iso8859_1    "$FILE1" 
# detox -s iso8859_1 -v "$FILE1" # v=verbose 
ls -alF s1*    # List all filenames starting with s1
```

`script2` is not working:

> error = No such file or directory

`script2` auto detects a new file in `DIR1 = ~/Downloads` and `script2` being On Access `DIR1` will eventually run
clamscan for a virus during testing, `FILE1` is manually pasted into `DIR1` to simulate a download.

Various quoting results:

```shell
detox -s iso8859_1  "$FILE1"    # No such file or directory
detox -s iso8859_1 '"$FILE1"'   # No such file or directory
detox -s iso8859_1 ""$FILE1""   # posting errors then ok result
```

`script2`

```shell
clear 
DIR1=$HOME/Downloads    # DIR1=/home/x/Downloads 
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,moved_to --format '%w%f' "$DIR1" |while read FILE1
do 
ls -alF s1*             # List all filenames starting with s1
detox -s iso8859_1 ""$FILE1"" 
ls -alF s1*             # List all filenames starting with s1
done
```

`script2` has errors then okay results:

```shell
s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
```

But there are many errors:

```shell
rw-rw-r-- 1 x x 1153263 Mar 13 11:36 's1 Ä Ö Ü - ä ö ü Science & < > " 1 \ 2 ⁄ 3 | ? * (&&9&&&) ::::z.pdf'
/home/x/Downloads/s1: No such file or directory
Ä: No such file or directory
Ö: No such file or directory
Ü: No such file or directory
-: No such file or directory
ä: No such file or directory
ö: No such file or directory
ü: No such file or directory
Science: No such file or directory
&: No such file or directory
<: No such file or directory
>: No such file or directory
": No such file or directory
2: No such file or directory
⁄: No such file or directory
3: No such file or directory
|: No such file or directory
(&&9&&&): No such file or directory
::::z.pdf: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x 1153263 Mar 13 11:36 s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x  1153263 Mar 13 11:36 s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 x x 1153263 Mar 13 11:36 s1_A_A-Aoe-A_A_pp_A_Science_and_1_2_a_3-and_and_9_and_and_and-z.pdf
```

#### What does `detox` mean?

- `detox` = clean up filenames
- The `detox` utility renames files to make them
  easier to work with.
- It removes spaces and other such annoyances.
- It'll also translate or cleanup Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) characters encoded in 8-bit ASCII, Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8, and CGI escaped characters.

#### `inotifywait` = wait for changes to files using inotify

- `inotifywait` efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's `inotify(7)` interface.
- It is suitable for waiting for changes to files from shell scripts.
- It can either exit once an event occurs, or continually execute and output events as they occur.

How to detox filenames in a bash script with no errors posted?

Comment: Probably `while read FILE1` is to blame. See [Understanding `IFS= read -r line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618). Later `""$FILE1""` is an empty string, unquoted `$FILE1` and another empty string – almost equivalent to unquoted `$FILE1`, thus [wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).